# How to translate the url to the right route when the locationtype = history in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I wrote a simple emberjs application,and set the router location type to 'history'

so i get some url from

http://localhost/#/post/1

to

http://localhost/post/1

the url changed by emberjs locally

however,when i refresh the page,i got an error

```
Cannot GET /post/1
```

seems nodejs cannot recognize that url

so,i wonder how to remap the absolute url to the route?

could you give me some hints?

thanks

Comment: If you use express on the server then you need a wildcard route(it must be last route in your app) like app.get('/*', function(...){res.render('index'.... to always render the index page.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your ajaxSetup in your app.js like this:

```
Ember.$.ajaxSetup( {
    beforeSend : function (xhr)
    {
        this.url = 'http://localhost' + this.url;
    },
    dataType   : // e.g.'json',
    contentType: // e.g.'application/json',
    crossDomain: true

});
```